# How to wait for on view to run before executing other views in Vue.js 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using vue.js version 2. I currently have a few different pages that share some data globally from another view that is a dropdown in the menu bar at the top.

Ideally I want that view for the dropdown to be executed before anything else on the app. As there are some variables being set in the store like so:

```
  <script>
  @Component
  export default class CurrentData extends Vue {
    isLoading = true;
    hasError = false;
    items = [];
    currentDataPeriod = '';
    setCurrentDataPeriod(item) {
      this.$store.commit('setItemData', item.data);
    }
  
    mounted() {
      this.$http.get(process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL + '/data_period', {
      }).then(response => {
        this.items = response.data;
        this.setCurrentDataPeriod(this.items[0]);
      }).catch(() => {
        this.hasError = true;
      }).finally(() => {
          this.isLoading = false;
        }
      );
    }
  }
  </script>
```

However when I navigate to another page this then executes what has been `mounted` it doesn't execute the above view first.

```
@Component
export default class ItemData extends Vue {
    items = [];
    mounted() {
      this.getRandomData();
    }

    getRandomData() {
      this.$http.get(process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL + '/random', {
        params: {
        itemData: this.$store.getters.itemData,
      },
      }).then((response) => {
        this.items = response.data;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
}
```

In the view above every time it is called when I try to call the store getters, it processes this before `CurrentData` view.

What I want to achieve is that every time the `ItemData` view is called, if the `$store.getters.itemData` is not set i.e. is null, then wait for it to not be null. I have been looking at promises, but a bit confused on how that would work with different views as opposed to functions.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Parent created hook runs before Child created hook but Parent mounted hook runs after Child mounted hook. I see though that you're dealing with async API calls, so the order of the hooks doesn't particularly matter here.  You can't trust that the async function will resolve at any specific time.  You'll want to use a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) which can run code whenever some "watched" state changes.

Comment: Thanks, I just implemented a watcher, and is working all good.